# A file was included in /_layouts/default.html that is a symlink or does not exist in your _includes directory

Tags: github-pages

When I try to build my github.io page, I get this error.

```
A file was included in /_layouts/default.html that is a symlink or does not exist in your _includes directory.
```

What does this error mean? Here is my Github website: https://github.com/zechnegli/zecheng.github.io.

Thanks!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvkAD.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you have a link in `_layouts/default.html` that references a file that does not exist.

Checking `_layouts/default.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    {% include head.html %}
    <body id="page-top" class="index">
    {% include nav.html %}
    {% include header.html %}
    {% include portfolio_grid.html %}
    {% include about.html %}

    {% if site.contact == "static" %}
    {% include contact_static.html %}
    {% elsif site.contact == "disqus" %}
    {% include contact_disqus.html %}
    {% else %}
    {% include contact.html %}
    {% endif %}

    {% include footer.html %}
    {% include modals.html %}
    {% include js.html %}
    </body>
</html>
```

All of the `included` files must be in `_includes` directory:

[image: includes]

As you can see at least `contact_disqus.html` is missing.